# How do I handle nullable fields using either the Mono<Connection> or the DatabaseClient provided by R2dbc in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am at a loss for how to contruct an efficient query in R2dbc (java) using spring-webflux (reactive). Using the DatabaseClient object provided by R2dbc (or alternatively, a Connection object), it seems that I am only able to call different variations of one of these two methods: `bind(Object field, Object value)` or `bindNull(Object field, Class<?> type)`. If I have a schema, and a corresponding class in Java, with multiple nullable fields, how am I expected to handle this [somewhat] efficiently?

Take for example:

```
public Flux<Item> saveOrUpdate(Item entity) {

   Mono<Connection> connection = this.connection; 

   Flux<? extends Result> itemFlux = connection
       .doOnError(e -> e.printStackTrace())
           .flatMapMany(connect  ->  connect.createStatement(INSERT_OR_UPDATE_ITEM)
                .bind("itemId", entity.getItemId()).returnGeneratedValues("itemid")
                .bind("auditId", entity.getTx().getId())
                .bind("itemNum", entity.getItemNum())
                .bind("itemCat", entity.getItemCat()) //nullable
                 // How would I know when to use this?
                .bindNull("sourcedQty", Integer.class) //nullable
                .bind("makeQty", entity.getMakeQty())
                .bind("nameShown", entity.getNameShown()) //nullable
                .bind("price", entity.price())
                .bind("dateCreated", entity.getDateCreated()) //nullable
                .add()
                .execute())...
   ...
}
```

OR

```
public Mono<Item> saveOrUpdate(Item entity){

   Mono<Item> itemMono = databaseClient.execute.sql(INSERT_OR_UPDATE_ITEM)
      .bind("itemId", entity.getItemId()).returnGeneratedValues("itemid")
                .bind("auditId", entity.getTx().getId())
                .bind("itemNum", entity.getItemNum())
                .bind("itemCat", entity.getItemCat())
                .bind("sourcedQty", entity.getSourcedQty()) 
                .bind("makeQty", entity.getMakeQty())
                .bind("nameShown", entity.getNameShown())
                .bind("price", entity.price())
                .bind("dateCreated", entity.getDateCreated())
                .as(Item.class)
                .fetch()
                .one()...
   ...
}
```

For my nullable fields I can replace .bind with .bindNull of course. The problem is that if I do call bind, the value cannot be null. And if I call bindNull, the value must be null. How would I be able to call one or the other based on whether my value is actually null? I already know that I can just make a bunch of methods for each scenerio or call something along the lines of retryOnError. But if I want to do a `insertOrUpdate(List<Item> items)` this would be wasting a ton of time/resources. Ideally I would like to do something analogous to `if (field == null) ? bindNull("field", field.class) : bind("field", myObj.field)` somewhere somehow. If that is clearly off the table, I am still interested in figuring out a way to implement this is as efficiently as possible given what I'm working with. Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: To clarify your question: You want to retain a fluent style while binding potentially `null` values and you're asking how to achieve that.

Comment: Sounds like an acceptable way to phrase it. My actuql dataset contains more null values than the sample I made here. I would like to make methods similar to this one nearly as efficient as executing a prepared statement with jdbc, for example. I don’t want to use hooks or wrappers or insert values that do not adhere to the conventions of the data already in the database. So I care a lot about style in that sense. But I’m open to ideas that require a bit of compromise. I’m new to both r2dbc and reactive so it’s very possible that I’ve overlooked a simple solution or a smart workaround.

Comment: I’d also be interested to hear of a way to write the sql statement so that I could just use .bind and let the database figure the rest out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are two questions:

1. How to bind potentially nullable values to a `Statement`/`DatabaseClient` in a fluent style?
2. How to let the database figure the rest out?

R2DBC and Spring Data R2DBC make `null` handling explicit by requiring either binding a value to your `Statement` or binding a `null`. There's no method of accepting a potentially nullable argument. There are two reasons for that:

1. You should deal with nullability to make obvious what happens there. That's a good habit to handle nullable values instead of making `null` handling implicit. The implicit nature of `null` is what causes the most bugs.
2. Being explicit is required by databases. Parametrized statements with placeholders consist on the execution side of two chunks: The SQL statement itself and parameters bindings (descriptors). A parameter descriptor requires an association to a placeholder, type information (`VARCHAR`, `BIT`, `INT`, …) and the actual value. With calling `bind(…)` with a value, a driver can derive the type information. When binding a `null` value, the driver requires an additional type of information. Otherwise, we cannot execute the query.

That being said:

1. There's no API like `bindPotentiallyNull("auditId", entity.getTx().getId(), Integer.class)`
2. You cannot do anything within the SQL query because binding parameter information is supplied by auxiliary methods.

We face a similar issue when talking about stored procedures, because stored procedures require additional details about in/out/in-out parameters. We discussed potential wrapper types like

```
Parameters.in(@Nullable T value, Class<? super T> valueType)
```

so these could be used as wrappers in

```
bind("auditId", Parameters.in(entity.getTx().getId(), Integer.class))
```

Further details:

- [Mailing list discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/r2dbc/12nq6d1l62Q)
- [Postgres protocol documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-message-formats.html)
- [Microsoft SQL Server: sp_cursorprepare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-cursorprepare-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks for your response @mp911de. Not exactly what I wanted to hear, but still great info - definitely useful to know. I'll go ahead and accept this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Either setting a value or null can be done using the `Parameter` class as shown below:

```java
import org.springframework.r2dbc.core.Parameter;

// rest of the code

.bind("customerId", Parameter.fromOrEmpty(o.getCustomerId(), UUID.class))
```

Earlier, it was `SettableValue.fromOrEmpty`, which is not deprecated.